# Understanding frequency in cuboid acoustic resonator

Tags: waves, resonance

We have a box with a speaker in the corner:
[image]

There is a formula for a frequency: $\nu=\sqrt{\nu _x^2+\nu _y^2+\nu _z^2}$, where $\nu _x$,$\nu _y$ and $\nu _z$ can be any resonant frequencies in each direction $\left(\nu _n=\frac{n c}{2 L}\right)$. My question is what does this frequency represent? If the air is in a superposition of standing waves in $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions, shouldn't then each point move in some Lissajous path? In which case what is the meaning of thif frequency? Am I understanding something wrong? Also the same thing appears in the planck law derivation. Also the experiment shows, that $\sqrt{\nu _x^2+\nu _y^2+\nu _z^2}$ frequencies actually get emplified.

Comment: The air is *not* in a superposition of $x$, $y$ and $z$ modes (that is a sum of those modes) – then they would not have a defined eigenfrequency (except in the degenerate case where $\nu_x = \nu_y$ or so). Rather they are the *products* of such modes (and those are again valid modes with said frequency $\nu$, as can be seen by solving the wave equation by a separation ansatz: $\phi(x,y,z,t) = \phi_x(x) \phi_y(y) \phi_z(z) \phi_t(t)$).

Answer (score 1):

The frequencies $\nu_x$, $\nu_y$ and $\nu_z$ represent waves traveling in parallel to the walls of the box, and bouncing off the opposite walls. They are called *axial* modes.

If the wave travels at an angle and bounces off two or all three pairs of the walls, the mode is called *tangential* or *oblique*.

The frequency of a mode can be calculated as

$$\nu = \frac{c}{2}\sqrt{
\left(\frac{n_x}{L_x}\right)^2
+ \left(\frac{n_y}{L_y}\right)^2
+ \left(\frac{n_z}{L_z}\right)^2
}\ ,$$
where $L_x$, $L_y$ and $L_z$ are the dimensions of the box, and a combination of natural numbers $(n_x, n_y, n_z)$ represent the mode. For axial modes, only one of them is nonzero; two for tangential, and three for oblique. This is where the formula you gave: $\nu = \sqrt{\nu_x^2 + \nu_y^2 + \nu_z^2}$ comes from.

Answer (score 0):

That frequency represents the longest (half) wavelength in air that can be fitted into a box with those dimensions. It's the *diagonal mode* with velocity *nodes* at the two diagonal corners and a velocity *maximum* in the center.

If you sweep the speaker's frequency and measure the sound loudness inside the box, you'll see a peak corresponding to that frequency in the box's response curve. this is *amplification by resonance*.

Here is another experiment to perform:

Take a hammer and tap each side of the box in the center. You will discover that each different-sized side of the box has its own resonant frequency. If you drive the speaker at one of these frequencies you will note that the box does a poor job of blocking sound from escaping from the box at that frequency.